# calling html onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm currently trying to call two functions from a javascript within html page.

Im unable to get this to work correctly. I have looked thru stackoverflow but cant seem to find the right solution to my problem.

Html code:

```
     <script src="js/check.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 

<section class="main">
                <form class="form-2">
                    <h1><span class="log-in">CPE Logistics Log in</span></h1>
                    <p class="float">
                        <label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Tech ID:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="login" placeholder="Tech ID" id="techid">
                    </p>
                  <p align="center" class="float2">
                    Select Duration in Days</p>
                    <p class="float2">
                    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="0 to 13 Days" /> 0 to 13 Days</p>
                    <p class="float2">
                      <input type="radio" name="duration" value="14 to 27 Days" />
                      14 to 27 Days</p>
                    <p class="float2">
                      <input type="radio" name="duration" value="28+ Days" />
                      28+ Days</p>
                    <p class="clearfix"> 
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Forward Logistics" id="log-fwd" onclick="return filledin();return check()"/> 
                    <input type="submit1" name="submit" value="Reverse Logistics" id="log-rvse" onclick="return filledin();return check1()"/>
                    </p>
    </form>​​
            </section>

        </div>

    </body>
```

Here is javascript check.js

```
function filledin()
{
var empt = document.getElementById("techid").value;
if (empt == "")
{
jAlert('Valid Tech ID Required', 'Alert Dialog');
return false;
}
}


function check()
{
    var dur = document.getElementsByName("duration");
    var len = dur.length    
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(dur[i].checked)
        {
        var url="http://wbv-sat-p0001:1013/ViewData.aspx?assetDirection=Forward&filterType=Tech ID&filterValue=" + document.getElementById("techid").value + "&categoryType=Status 7 Duration Margin&categoryValue=" + dur[i].value + "&techType=";
location.href=url;
return false;
        }
    }
}



function check1()
{
    var dur = document.getElementsByName("duration");
    var len = dur.length

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(dur[i].checked)
        {
        var url="http://wbv-sat-p0001:1013/ViewData.aspx?assetDirection=Reverse&filterType=Tech ID&filterValue=" + document.getElementById("techid").value + "&categoryType=Status 7 Duration Margin&categoryValue=" + dur[i].value + "&techType=";
location.href=url;
return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the alert box if no tech id is inputted.
When you select a radio button and click either one of the submit buttons it returns this as the URL

```
file:///C:/Users/*****/Desktop/cpe1/cpe2.html?login=13293&duration=14+to+27+Days&submit=Forward+Logistics&submit=Reverse+Logistics
```

If i remove the function filledin() from the onclick i get the correctly formatted URL.

```
http://wbv-sat-p0001:1013/ViewData.aspx?assetDirection=Forward&filterType=Tech%20ID&filterValue=13293&categoryType=Status%207%20Duration%20Margin&categoryValue=14%20to%2027%20Days&techType=
```

How do i solve this so it runs both functions? I need error checking on the tech Id Input and to then format the correct URL on submission once tech id is inputted and radio button selected. If this can be solved i can then add the error checking for radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick method will treat whatever you put inside it as a function. In your case, you're trying to do something like:

```
function () {
    return filledin();
    return check();
}
```

So, it will always return whatever filledin evaluates and will never reach the check function.

The simple way to solve your problem would be doing something like this in your onclick call:

```
function validateAndCheck () {
    // The way that filledin is implemented will always return false or undefined
    if (filledin() != null) {
        return check();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope that this helps you.

Comment: Sorry i must be missing something. I dont understand. where would i add this new function within the js file? I added it at beginning, changed the onclick to point to the new function but it occurs to me that it cant check if filledin() is null as it hasn't run that function yet. Excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You can put the validateAndCheck function at the end of your js file and call it on the onclick. After that, your input node should be something like this:

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Forward Logistics" id="log-fwd" onclick="return validateAndCheck()"/>